# Right to Left react native - Localisation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, right-to-left

Hi I have a simple view with few `Text` fields. I want to implement Localisation for it. so when the language is Arabic I want the `Text` fields to be Right to Left.

For which I had to write each `Text` field in a View and `flexDirection: 'row'` and  `justifyContent: 'flex-start'` to the `View`.

```
 <View>
        <View style={stylesLocal.headerContainer}>
            <Text>First text</Text>
        </View>        
        <View style={stylesLocal.headerContainer}>
            <Text>Second text</Text>
        </View>
</View>

const stylesLocal = StyleSheet.create({
  headerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  }
})
```

Is there any other simpler way to do this.
Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

Add `textAlign:'right'` to `<Text>` and this should work

Comment: Hello @Roozbeh if I use `textAlign:'right'` then irrespective of RTL or LTR layout it will always be aligned to right which is wrong. I only want it to be right if it is RTL and left if it is LTR. I am sure I should be using `flex-start` and `flex-end` but that is only possible with `flex-direction` and each Text to be within a `view`. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: for making a two lang app i guess u should make 2 style sheet